# Dark mode doesn't work in system settings

Tags: settings

Today when I launched system settings app I found out that dark mode doesn't work in it[image]

But in other applications it works. For example - file explorer[image]

Comment: Same problem here, any news on that?

Comment: Yup I have the same issue, thought I had done something really stupid. I am also having issues with the zoom effect on plank as well. Loads of weird this happening on my system of late

Comment: yes, i also seen this problems. Hopelly soon will update.

Comment: Also seems that now even the menu is no longer dark either with the recent updates

Comment: Apps menu doesn't use dark theme either. I'm on openSuse Tumbleweed with Pantheon desktop

Comment: same here after several updates, also the applications pannel it turned light. any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar issue here, Has to do something with the new update, I know they've been working on dark mode override(per app dark mode preference). But still, have to wait for official statement.

Answer (score 0):

Unless Dark Mode it's not officially supported in EOS, a workaround in this thread: https://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/comments/gxhsi9/slowly_losing_dark_theme_with_each_update/